# Shadowing core functions in namespaces in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to shadow a core function in one of my namespaces. The codes work like below:

core.clj:

```clj
(ns test.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?])
  (:require [test.z :refer [zero?]]))

(defn -main
  (prn (zero? 1)))
```

z.clj:

```clj
(ns test.z
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?]))
(defn zero? [x] (+ x 1))
```

When running, it shows error messages:

```
; (err) WARNING: zero? already refers to: #'clojure.core/zero? in namespace: test.z, being replaced by: #'test.z/zero?
```

I'm not sure if Clojure permits this, can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

---

Edit: That seems to be the problem, but the error message is really confusing. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `-main` function is missing an argument declaration so, as the code stands, it is not legal. However, if you add the arguments, it works as expected with the standard Clojure CLI:

```
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/test.core$ cat src/test/core.clj
(ns test.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?])
  (:require [test.z :refer [zero?]]))

(defn -main [& args]
  (prn (zero? 1)))
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/test.core$ cat src/test/z.clj
(ns test.z
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?]))
(defn zero? [x] (+ x 1))
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/test.core$ clojure -M -m test.core
2
seanc@DESKTOP-30ICA76:~/clojure/test.core$ clj
Clojure 1.10.2
user=> (require '[test.core])
nil
user=> (test.core/-main)
2
nil
user=>
```

As you can see, there are no warnings. It's possible the WARNING shows up because of the error in your `-main` function (missing arguments). It's also possible that whatever tooling you are using to load/run the code is doing something wrong/inadvisable -- but you haven't given any details about that.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need `:refer-clojure` in both namespaces if you follow the normal convention of using a NS alias us the the file that ***uses*** the shadowed function.  Here is an example that works below.

For the NS ***defining*** the function:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?]))

(defn zero?
  [arg]
  (= "nada" arg))
```

For the NS ***using*** the function:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [demo.core :as demo]))

(dotest
  (is (demo/zero? "nada"))
  (isnt (demo/zero? 0)))
```

With output:

```
> lein test
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

lein test _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2    Java 15
-------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.core

Ran 2 tests containing 2 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

The above is based upon [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

---

You could also do it this way:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?])
  (:require
    [demo.core :refer :all]))

(dotest
  (is (zero? "nada"))
  (isnt (zero? 0)))
```

which is more like your original question.  However, with this version, each calling NS is required to include the disclaimer `(:refer-clojure :exclude [zero?])` so people usually write code like in the 1st example and use a function name like `demo/zero?`

Comment: In this case, they DO need the :refer-clojure to :exclude [zero?] because they are trying to :refer [zero?] into the calling NS. Without that exclusion, you get a warning when the new zero? function is referred into the calling NS.